# sqlite3 insert row if unique

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Here is my table schema:

```
downloadstbl

_id int not null auto
url text not null
filename text not null
date text not null)
```

I would like to insert a row only if there isnt a row in the table already with the same url.

E.g, if the following row exists:

```
_id=1
url="http://google.com/img.jp"
filename="img.jp"
date="11/03/2012"
```

then if I try to insert another row that has url="http://google.com/img.jp" the sql statement will not insert to avoid duplicate rows for the same remote file.

I know I could probably do this by first doing a SELECT and checking for whether a row already exists, however I would like to check if this is possible at the point of insertion to make things more robust/clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would add the `UNIQUE` keyword to the `url` column.
Then, when inserting, use this `INSERT OR IGNORE` instead of `INSERT`.

Answer (score 2):

You can (and should, for data integrity reasons) add a unique constraint to the `url` column by adding `UNIQUE(url)` to the SQL create statement for your table or just adding `unique` after `not null`. This will cause an insertion to fail when inserting a row where the URL is already in the table. Then you can use `insertWithOnConflict` to check for the result of the insert.